# JS/JQuery, Grid, and element blocking 'onclick' function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, grid

Unfortunately I have not been able to figure out exactly what 'principal' I am missing here.

I made this little 'page sort' widget-- Or click any 'sub page' which will transition it to the front and reorder/restack all the pages:

https://codepen.io/abalducci/pen/aEYPmz

This seems to be working 'okay' at least for me.

However, when I try to start to embed this in a larger application the 'onclick' function is being blocked in the area where the widget overlaps with other content.

i.e.

```
<div id="page_1" class="paper foldedEdge" onclick="test(this)">
```

https://codepen.io/abalducci/pen/OzbRME

I know that the Z-index is okay, or I've sent the overlapping wiki logo all the way to the back, and when I actually call the widget remove the wiki logo/search box completely from the DOM using JQuery.

But one will notice 'onclick' works if you click at the very 'bottom' part of the 'virtual page' of the widget, but not where they start to overlap.

What part of the code or layout here is 'blocking' the activation of this function call in this area ? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Actually I don't even feel I need a 'tailored' answer--- But I'd like to just better understand what is the 'rule' for elements on top of elements and their related Javascript calls out of the DOM. If Z-Index isn't the determinant, than what is ?